# i created a wifi access point on my raspberry pi but it doesn't serve internet to clients why does this happen

Tags: raspbian, wifi, dhcp, bridge

I created a  wireless router with RPI3 but isc-dhcp-server is not working

i made changes to dhcp.conf ie

uncommenting authorative and also

subnet 192.168.1.3 netmask 255.255.255.0 {
range 192.168.1.10 192.168.42.52;
option broadcast-address 192.168.1.255;
option routers 192.168.1.5;
default-lease-time 600;
max-lease-time 7200;
option domain-name "local";
option domain-name-servers 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4;
}

Answer (score 1):

The link you referenced seems to be an obsolete copy of the Foundation tutorial.
Try [Setting up a Raspberry Pi as a routed wireless access point](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/configuration/wireless/access-point-routed.md)